# Computing tensor product $k[t]/(t^p) \otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p)} k[t]/(t^p)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be a field of chracteristic $p>0$. I want to show that $M=k[t]/(t^p) \otimes_{k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p)} k[t]/(t^p)$ is not isomorphic to $k[t]/(t^p)$ as $k$-algebra. Here the map from $k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p) \to k[t]/(t^p) $ is $x \to t$ and $y \to t$. The other map $k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p) \to k[t]/(t^p) $ is $x \to t$ and $y \to 0$. So, the algebra structure of  $k[t]/(t^p)$ is different on both sides.

is it true that $M$ is not isomorphic to $k[t]/(t^p)$ (as a $k$-algrebra )?

Comment: If $A\to B$ is a surjective map of commutative rings, $B\otimes_A B=B\otimes_B B=B$, so I do not understand your question.

Comment: I changed my maps now, so what would happen in this case?

Comment: How are you planning to make the tensor product into an algebra?

Comment: Take an element $p\otimes q$ in your product, and note that if $q$ is divisible by $t$, then 

$$p\otimes q=p\otimes tq_0 =p\otimes xq_0=px\otimes q_0 =py\otimes q_0=p\otimes yq_0 = 0 .$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $M$ has a natural $k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p)$-algebra structure. Also, $k[x,y]/(x^p,y^p)$ is a $k$-algebra. Shouldn't that impose a natural $k$-algebra structure on $M$ ?

Comment: @grontim Sure. In which case the computation above shows that as an algebra the product is generated by the elementary tensors of the form $p\otimes 1$.

Comment: So, it is isomorphic to $k[t]/(t^p)$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I may be misunderstanding something but shouldn't all tensors of the form $t^1\otimes1$ also vanish? Because $t^i \otimes 1= yt^{i-1}\otimes 1= t^{i-1} \otimes y.1 =0$? Also that means $M $ is just $k$?